# TYPO3 Image From Extension

Tags: typo3

I'm a typo newbie, and was wondering, how I can make the following code work in my HTML Template file:

```
<img src="EXT:extension-name/Resources/Public/Images/Logo/logo-white.png" alt="logo.png">
```

Looking forward to your anwers, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done in an HTML file but within a Fluid template file you should use the [`uri.resource` viewhelper](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/Uri/ResourceViewHelper.html):

```
<img src="{f:uri.resource(path: 'Images/Logo/logo-white.png')}" alt="Actual explanation of the logo content">
```

If used within an Extbase plugin there is nothing else to do.

For templates using the [`FLUIDTEMPLATE` content object](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html) you'll need to set the extension name, for example with an `extensionName: 'MyExt'` as argument:

```
<img src="{f:uri.resource(path: 'Images/Logo/logo-white.png', extensionName: 'MyExt')}" alt="Actual explanation of the logo content">
```

Alternatively use [`controllerExtensionName`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html#extbase-controllerextensionname) in your TypoScript setup.

Comment: Like that? <img src="{f:uri.extensionName: 'ext-name'.resource(path: 'Public/Images/Logo/logo-white.png')}" alt="Actual explanation of the logo content">

Comment: Uups, just learned it from here: [viewhelper](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/Uri/ResourceViewHelper.html)